# How to control order of result from iterator in python

Tags: python, iterator, pathlib

I use `pathlib.Path().iterdir()` to get sub-dictionary of the path.

Under `/home/yuanyi/workspace/app`, there are 4 folders: `01`, `02`, `03`, `04`.

```
from pathlib import Path
for subdir in Path('/home/yuanyi/workspace/app').iterdir():
    print(subdir)
```

But the result is not ordered.

```
/home/yuanyi/workspace/app/02
/home/yuanyi/workspace/app/03
/home/yuanyi/workspace/app/01
/home/yuanyi/workspace/app/00
```

Wht the result is not the following:

```
/home/yuanyi/workspace/app/01
/home/yuanyi/workspace/app/02
/home/yuanyi/workspace/app/03
/home/yuanyi/workspace/app/04
```

I want to know how the iterator works, and what's the best method to get ordered result.

Comment: Out of interest, what OS are you using?

Comment: From the [Path.iterdir() docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir): "The children are yielded in arbitrary order, ..."

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use "sorted()"

[Built-in Functions Python - sorted()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

```
from pathlib import Path
for subdir in sorted(Path('/some/path').iterdir()):
    print(subdir)
```

**NOTE:** @NamitJuneja points out, This changes iterating over a generator to iterating over a list. Hence if there are a huge number of files in the memory, loading them all into the memory (by loading them into a list) might cause problems.

On my Mac, the iterdir() method returns the list already sorted. So that looks system dependent. What OS are you using?

Comment: This changes iterating over a generator to iterating over a list. Hence if there are a huge number of files in the memory, loading them all into the memory (by loading them into a list) might cause problems

Comment: Thanks, @NamitJuneja, I've incorporated your comment into the answer. Edit as you see fit!

Answer (score 3):

Think you should figure out the result from this,

```
>>> l = ['/home/yuanyi/workspace/app/02',
'/home/yuanyi/workspace/app/03', '/home/yuanyi/workspace/app/01']
>>> for i in sorted(l, key=lambda m: int(m.split('/')[-1])):
    print i


/home/yuanyi/workspace/app/01
/home/yuanyi/workspace/app/02
/home/yuanyi/workspace/app/03
>>>
```

or

```
for i in sorted(l, key=lambda m: int(m.split(os.sep)[-1])):
    print i
```

Comment: Well, do you means I need to do some works else to sort the order? Is there any methods of iterator to get ordered result?

Comment: Very nice try, but only `os.walk()` guarantees [top-down ordering](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk). I believe this is a small example but that's likely what the poster expects. Unfortunately, none of the `Pathlib` variants provide this guarantee so the user must implement their own sort. How to do top-down sort?

Comment: Ahh, yes, I found the answer by sifting through [Python source](https://github.com/python/): So `iterdir()` uses `listdir()` and `glob()` uses `scandir()`. Scandir is picked up from the `os` module. Since `os.walk()` also uses `scandir()`, it looks like the closest thing to `os.walk()` is `pathlib.glob()` but I'm not sure how that could be used to make it look like `os.walk()` output (the art). If you're wondering why some parts of Pathlib use `listdir()` it was a [ruling by Guido](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2013-November/130583.html).